# Access Report Query pulling from Form instead of table

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have a report that changes based on the query used in the record source.
I did this to consolidate 6 different reports that printed the same formate and to the same label printer but they all used different data types/sources. I was able to convert all by 1. 
The one I am having trouble with is one where there is a form, with a combobox and a textbox. The combobox has a table that its connected to with 11 different symbols ranging from Hearts to & and @ stuff like that. The textbox will take any number/text combo.

When I run a query that I set up with `[Forms]![frmPrintPtouchLabel]![txtName]` and `[Forms]![frmPrintPtouchLabel]![cmbSymbol]`.
The query pulls the right information except for the symbol that columb is left blank. Can anyone provide any reasoning as to why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say symbol, what are you referring to?  #Name?

Comment: Symbols like ♥ and █

Comment: Here is the unique 11 symbols we use:
        Symbol

        &

        +

        ■

        ☼

        ♥

        ●

        @

        ♦

        ▲

        #

        ♪

Comment: I tested on Access 2013 and I was able to replicate what you are trying to do with out any issues.  Can you provide some additional data from your application?  VBA Code, SQL, etc...

Comment: @SteveW Thank you. Your comment gave me confidence to just go back and start from scratch. I created a new query and did a test. Now its working! I guess I was overwhelmed and I should have done what any other programmer would have done and stepped away for a few hours to clear the head. Thank you so much.

Comment: It happens to all of us.  Just this morning I've scrapped a Web app 3 times already and started over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was fluke somewhere in my code or I was just over thinking something. After setting up a blank query I set a field: `Symbol: [Forms]![frmPrintPtouchLabel]![cmbSymbol]`, and a field `Name: [Forms]![frmPrintPtouchLabel]![txtName]`
and I set up a button in a form that does `DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_TestQuery"`, in that same form there is the combobox with the Symbols, and a textbox for the Name, when I input those two and click the button the query opens with the proper information. Thanks for all that helped.